# How do I create a Detailed View for my UITableView to allow me to edit data in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm new to iOS, Objective-C and have only done a small ammount of OO programming before but enjoying the challenge of trying to create this app.

Summary of app:
I have a view which is just a form to enter information into the Core Data database eg. Name, Address & Telephone. Then another view which contains a Table View which lists all the names of people currently in database.

However this is where i'm stuck...

I have created a detailed view so that when a user selects a Table Cell the detailed view loads but i want to get data from Core Data back into the form they used to originally enter the data so it can be modified/editted and re-saved back to Core Data.

What are the best practicies of doing this?

I will need to pass some data forward to the detailed view, which know how to do, but what should I pass? how do I tell the detailed view which row of data in the Core Data database I wish to load?

Do I pass the tableview indexPath.row value? does this correspond to anything I can filter down in CoreData when loading the detailed view?

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies, would appreciate any help from methodology to online tuts

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I think you can see Apple sample code here : [CoreRecipes sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I have looked at that before on my quest to find an answer to this before posting. That project contains alot of other code and methods. I found it hard to try and understand what I needed from it. Will try again tho.

Answer (score 0):

Picking out bits from CoreRecipes sample code as suggested by TheRonin I did the following.

Create an iVar of Core-Data DataModel object on the DetailedViewController

```
DataStore *enquiry;
```

On the tableview view under didSelectRowAtIndex setup Core-Data DataModel object and Detailed view controller,

```
DataStore *enquiry = (DataStore *)[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

ShowEnquiryDetail *detailViewController = [[ShowEnquiryDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowEnquiryDetail" bundle:nil ];
```

set the Data Model object in DetailedViewController

```
detailViewController.enquiry = enquiry;
```

then push the DetailedViewController on to navigation stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Then on the DetailedViewController you can access the data in the DataModel object from the selected row in Core-Data using enquiry.name, enquiry.email, etc...

**This isn't a well written answer and may use incorrect terminology but hopefully it will help someone in the same position I was.**